# Overriding Backbone methods with webpack

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, webpack

I am using **webpack** and trying to port some legacy code over.

One of the things the legacy code was doing was modifying the **sync** method on the **global Backbone** object something like this:

```
// override/sync.coffee
do (Backbone) ->
  _sync = Backbone.sync

  Backbone.sync = (method, entity, options = {}) ->
    _.defaults options,
      beforeSend: _.bind(methods.beforeSend, @, entity, method)
      complete: _.bind(methods.complete, @, entity, method)

    sync = _sync(method, entity, options)
```

**Then compilation was in this order**

```
// backbone.js
// override/sync.coffee
```

Now in Webpack system Backbone is no longer global, in each file I have to do 
`require('backbone').` So how should I re-implement these kind of overrides?

Comment: Don't know webpack but couldn't you `require` something that `require`s `backbone.js` and monkey patches it instead of `require`ing `backbone.js` directly?

Comment: Thank you that sounds doable!